# Negation in solr query

Tags: solr, solrj

I am trying the following query and get only zero results (I am supposed to get 10 results according to my dataset)

```
http://mymachine:8983/solr/select/?q=-(HOSTID:302)
```

I also tried the below query and got zero results yet again.

`http://mymachine:8983/solr/select/?q=NOT(HOSTID:302)`

However, I get 10 results(expected) when I put the query this way,

`http://mymachine:8983/solr/select/?q=-(HOSTID:302)AND(*:*)`

Why is this strange thing happening? Is it a bug in solr or am I missing something?

Comment: It does make sense to require something to "subtract" the negated term from. Solr probably doesn't implement negated searches of the index, but filters a preexisting set instead, and probably wouldn't implement `*:*` as a default if nothing else were specified. Performance of such a query might not be very good.

Comment: @Potatoswatter I understand it is a performance constraint and that is why I am looking for the proper way. Basically I am looking for something that would fetch me the MySQL equivalent of `Select * from table where hostid != 302`

Comment: If hostid is likely to be 302 for a large fraction of the entries, you likely need to adjust the schema to include a field indicating it's not 302, for best performance. You could use a wildcard field to test the concept without too much impact. But I'm still a Solr beginner so I won't further attempt to answer this ;v)

Comment: +1 for @Potatoswatter's comments - the negative query as far as I understand it is for filtering, unlike the SQL `NOT` operator. Lucene/Solr is optimized for retrieval, not database queries :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ahmet Arslan from the solr mailing list helped me with a solution. Just mentioning it here for future benefits.

Solr converts top level negative query (-field:something) into q=+*:* -field:something

It seems that you are missing that part.

org.apache.solr.search.QueryUtils

```
`/** Fixes a negative query by adding a MatchAllDocs query clause.
  * The query passed in *must* be a negative query.
  */
 public static Query fixNegativeQuery(Query q) {
   BooleanQuery newBq = (BooleanQuery)q.clone();
   newBq.add(new MatchAllDocsQuery(), BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
   return newBq;
 }`
```